# Is it possible to do android development effectively on vim?

Tags: vim, android

I prefer programming on **vim**, **however**, I heard that vim is not suitable for **java** development.
 
Is it true? Is it possible to do it without **IDE** effectively? 
If yes, how is it possible?

Comment: More info about developing Android Apps using vim: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masochism

Comment: Effectively, I would say "no" - there are a ton of components to Android development - Gradle build files, multiple permission schemas, etc. - that Vim can't create and you would need to know from scratch.  Android Studio helps build those files.

Comment: Android Studio has a plugin named `IdeaVIM` with huge popularity. I use Android studio with this plugin and I'm really happy since it feels like developing on VIM with all the benefits of Android Studio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Huge vim user myself, I faced the same question when moving in to Android Development a few years back.

Originally I used Eclipse while Android Studio was still in development. Once Android Studio hit full release, the switch from Eclipse to Android Studio was another pain, but now Android Studio feels "good" to use.

All I can say is download Android Studio and spend the time needed to use and learn the IDE. Android Studio is made for, and developed to make Android Apps.

If you are expanding from HTML / Javascript / CSS / PHP / "Something else" to Android, do not waste your time trying to set-up anything else. You will have nothing but issues and hand made scripts and other stuff to remember and manage. With Android Studio instead of that layer of complexity you will be using a menu option or even a shortcut key.

Personally I still use vim for everything except Android Apps. Android Studio is simply another tool that needs to be learned to do the job.

The only pain in the butt now is the constant updates, but the medium is still moving pretty quick and that is just how things go in App development. Without Android Studio you will need to update those scripts or need remember to download something else because something changed.

Keep it simple and use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Even Bram Moolenar himself said there are times when he has used some editor other than vim because it was better suited to the task, but he always lamented that, whilst they were better for the platform or whatever, they were worse at actual editing of text. If I recall correctly, doesn't android studio have some kind of blender type, 3d modelling environment? e.g. for creating things in virtual reality? In that case you literally dont have a choice because you are no longer editing text.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot more to Android Dev than editing a text file. The entire "package creation and signing" is a very important and complex step. 100% possible to create an APK without Android Studio, just a pain and prone to errors.

Comment: cool, out of interest what is an APK?, is that like androids equivalent to a `.deb` or `.rpm` package?

Comment: [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package) is the Android application package. It is the entire compiled "App Package" that you upload to the device (or Google Play). It is basically a ZIP file. with everything in it, in the correct format.

Comment: oh ok, and so if you use android studio, it will create this package and deal with the digital/crypto signing . But if you don't use android studio you would have to do this packaging and signing yourself?

Comment: Correct. I'm guessing the Eclim program in the other answer has some kind of Add-On that will do this, but Google is always making small changes and improvements to the entire process. Android Studio gets these changes very quickly (sometimes too quick).

Comment: Android Studio runs builds using Gradle, so you can do the same to easily produce builds

Comment: Ideavim in Android Studio gives you the full suite of tools for Android development, along with Vim keybindings. It is pretty good, though I miss some of my plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Eclim](http://eclim.org/). It gives you Eclipse IDE code/project support inside vim.

As you i was a vim user but i needed to do Java development. I now use vim / eclim for two years and i'm really happy with.

I do not Android dev but Eclim seems to support it: See [Create a Android project with Eclim](http://eclim.org/vim/java/android.html).